# How to use three-dot to do destructuring for types in typescript

Tags: typescript, flowtype

in flow I usually use the following

```
type A = {|
  a: string
|}
```

```
// in another file, import type A
type B = {|
  ...A,
  b: string,
|}
```

But when I'm doing similar in typescripts, it gives me `Member 'A' implicitly has an 'any' type.ts(7008)

```
type A = {
  a: string
}
```

```
// in another file, import type A
type B = {
  ...A,
  b: string,
}
```

what can I do to make this right? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use an intersection type:

```
type B = A & {b: string}
```

Or you can use interfaces:

```
interface B extends A {
    b: string
}
```

The difference is that an interface can have fields added to it by other `interface B` declarations elsewhere, whereas `type B = ...` cannot be modified after it is declared. See [the docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#differences-between-type-aliases-and-interfaces) for more details.